# WCF returning Streams or Strings?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, json

I've been constantly getting more and more frustrated with WCF and the return types.
I'm currently working on a method at the moment that reads data from SQL, creates new objects of a certain type based on the amount of data retrieved, and then assigns the object values with the data retrieved from SQL.

I have functionality in place to serialize to JSON and XML.
Ideally I would like to convert my serialized objects into strings so that I can read the response from a browser in the converted fashion, hopefully the following examples will be more explanatory.

The benefits I get from when I serialize my objects, and return a stream is that the formatting is perfect, and it is using my DataMembers in the classes, so a response would in JSON would look like:

```
{"GameID":1,"ProposalID":5}
```

however when I go to retrieve the data in the browser, it asks me to save the stream file, I open the stream in notepad to see this result. This isn't ideal as the result isn't coming up on the browser as a string.

If I return a string, I get the data, however it is not formatted properly using the DataMembers or any of the advantages from serializing and the information is therefore pretty bare and not meaningful:

```
"3151"
```

As you can see from this example, I am also retrieving 2 SQL fields of 2 variables each. And I am unsure as to how I can append results onto a stream as at the moment it is only returning the last result (5,1), let alone return them properly.

Although I'm not sure if I can paste a url of something that is what I would like to achieve, here it is anyway: http://api.justin.tv/api/user/show/justin.json

My immediate thought would be to use an XMLWriter or some kind to manually write the information, however I would like to be able to pay dividends to the serialization and DataMember features.

My return stream Code:

```
foreach (MatchProposal proposal in Proposals)
{
   returnStream = WriteJSON(SerializeToJSON(proposal));
}

public MemoryStream SerializeToJSON(object serializeObject)
{
   DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(serializeObject.GetType());
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, serializeObject);
   return memoryStream;
}

public Stream WriteJSON(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(json));
}
```

And my unfulfilled simple String returning code:

```
   WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
```

It simply returns the SQL Data.

I hope I've given enough information into what I've done so far and what I would like to achieve from the example given. 
In Short I would like to achieve what is written in the Justin.tv API, I would like to take advantage of the serialization, however when I browse to the return stream in a browser, I am greeted with a file download which I can open in notepad which is not ideal.

Thanks for any advice if I appear to have gotten lost at some point, or any resolutions I can implement :)

Regards,
 Ronald

Comment: Are you applying a ContentType to the response, e.g. `text/xml`, or `text/json`?

Comment: @MatthewAbbott no there is no contenttype declared, is this required for ideal stream returning?

Comment: I would imagine this is likely to be the problem. Because you are returning a `Stream` instead of an object, I think that no content type is being specified, so the browser doesn't know how to handle it - this prompts a download message. Try adding in a content type of `text/json` to see if that sorts the issue. I would then check what content type is being requested, and have your service adapt to match that.

Comment: Please show JavaScript code that you use to call the service (unless you are looking for just showing results of the call in the browser directly).

Comment: @MatthewAbbott Thank you this is exactly what was needed and thank you for the explanation. Now that I am returning the information correctly, do you happen to have any tips on how I can append a second object onto the same response?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the response, I am simply trying to just recall the information from the browser itself not an application. Matthew's advice was helpful, now I am trying to fathom how I can append a second object onto the stream.

Comment: @Rodney I've added my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you applying a ContentType to the response, e.g. `text/xml`, or `text/json`?

I would imagine this is likely to be the problem. Because you are returning a Stream instead of an object, I think that no content type is being specified, so the browser doesn't know how to handle it - this prompts a download message. Try adding in a content type of `text/json` to see if that sorts the issue. I would then check what content type is being requested, and have your service adapt to match that.

**Update** in regards to add a second object to the stream, I would recommend against trying to simply tack it on to the end of the stream. Instead, why not build a composite model, which contains two properties representing the objects to want to serialise and pass back from the service?