# How can I return XML from a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

The web service in question must return results of a stored procedure in SOAP XML.

I can return any object from a web service no problem, I'm even familiar with serializing JSON from an .asmx service but I'm totally stumped with the concept of returning XML from a web service who's job is to retrieve results from a stored procedure. It's very important to me this, so any help seriously appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: MSDN Tutorials... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf

Comment: this might be helpful too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730940/wcf-returning-streams-or-strings

Comment: I can also recommend this book http://www.amazon.com/RESTful-NET-Build-Consume-Services/dp/0596519206/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328109932&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning an `XmlNode`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    ...
    [OperationContract]
    XmlNode MyMethod(...);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe, appreciate your response. So supposing the job of this service is to return the results of a stored procedure - how/where would this 'conversion' from sql result to XML occur?? Thanks again.

Comment: @SkonJeet - There are many options.  The simplest is to have your OperationContract return a strongly-typed result (e.g. `MyType` or `IList<MyType>`) and leave the framework to do the serialization.  Or you could use the Xml classes in the .NET framework to generate the XML yourself, using the data returned by your `IDataReader`.

Comment: Thanks again for your time mate. So would you say that it would be 'acceptable' for me to code a web service that fetches the results of a stored procedure into an sqlreader (as normal) and then go through and convert all this to xml using the XML classes? Or are there more 'elegant' ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Other than returning XML as a string you can look at WCF REST http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388 which can be added to give you VS project templates for XML/JSON WCF projects.